# Pointless edit approved

Tags: support, edits, specific-edit

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4305403) was approved and should not have been. Is there some way to change it to rejected at this point?

Comment: Theoretically you could reject it as the post owner according to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions

Comment: I don't know if it still works after you rolled back the edit, maybe that counts as a subsequent edit.

Comment: The revision message *"modified logic when there are negative numbers in an array"* seems strange for a whitespace only edit, perhaps the editor forgot to include something.

Comment: Yeah my hunch is they forgot to update the code as the comment suggests the code does not cope with negative numbers?

Comment: Someone's getting points for a *pointless* edit??? Oh dear.

Comment: The edit wasn’t just pointless: It appears to be spam. Note that the edit message is complete nonsense. It appears that the user is simply attempting to gain points via spammy edits. This behaviour should probably be penalised (that said, it appears to be the user’s first such action).

Comment: (The answer is indeed wrong for some negative array, I pointed it out in a comment under the answer.)

Comment: @user000001 technically, he added backticks fencing, not whitespaces. See markdown view.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's best to assume good faith. A possible scenario: he made an edit, then realized during the grace period that the edit was wrong, and then restored the original code, while forgetting to remove the fences.

Comment: Interesting detail: The editor wrote "modified logic when there are negative numbers in an array" but there's absolutely no logic changed.

Comment: *hot cross-ref on **meta**.meta.stackoverflow.com: pointless question answered*  :P

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I tend to agree. All of this user's edits so far (four at this time) hit on one or more of the reasons I would reject an edit. I hesitate to raise a flag but maybe they should be notified before they get carried away and suspended.

Comment: I actually find it worse that two reviewers approved the edit despite the pointless content and the incorrect message. We may assume good faith for the editor but I don't see many excuses for the reviewers.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, moderators and OPs have overriding powers when a suggested edit has been reviewed and binding vote when it is still pending reviewing.

I see you are the OP. You can reject the edit - there should be a button at the top saying <kbd>Reject</kbd>. Click it and the edit will be rejected. However, you have now rolled back that edit, so there wouldn't be any button I suppose.

Some additional hunting: you can go and search suggestor's suggestion history to find other smelly stuff and flag one of their posts for moderator intervention. You can do the same for reviewers. But this is endless...

Comment: There is an important point for rejecting that edit, even after the rollback: teaching the editor that such an edit is not appreciated. That's important imo, if bad edits get approved, that behavior gets rewarded while it shouldn't be.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP rolled back the edit, instead of rejecting the suggested edit. Any subsequent edit removes the “reject” option, including rollbacks.

Comment: "*you can go and search suggestor's suggestion history to find other smelly stuff*" - I don't think there is a need for that. The user "*had 1 edit suggestion approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected*". You can see these stats, along with the stats for the reviewers when you click `(more)` at the bottom of the list of reviewers in [the suggested edit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4305403).

Comment: @ErikA Those who APPROVED the edit should be taught that they did something wrong

Comment: @Broman In some cases they are -- moderators have been known to reach out to people with a history/pattern of approving bad/harmful edits to let them know, either by literally mod-messaging them, review banning them, or both. In the event of a single bad edit approval, though, it's almost never worth it.

Comment: @ErikA people will always find ways to break out of the box, why bother with the edit when it basicly does not change anything. Instead, OP and editor get some reputation

Comment: @clockw0rk, reputation is a reward for doing things that benefit the site and community. Enough of it confers capabilities on the recipient that are intended to be contingent on them having demonstrated an interest in and ability to perform beneficial work.  It is therefore completely appropriate to go to some length to squash abuses of the system such as the subject of this question.